# Simplest way to return whether all flows have non-null latest value?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have this horrible code:

```kotlin
val flow1: Flow<SomeObject?>
        get() = // Not important
val flow2: Flow<SomeOtherObject?>
        get() = // Not important
val flow3: Flow<SomeThirdObject?>
        get() = // Not important

fun foo(): Boolean = runBlocking {
        flow1.lastOrNull() != null && flow2.lastOrNull() != null && flow3.lastOrNull() != null
    }
```

How can `foo()` be simplified?

Comment: Have you already verified that your code above behaves as you like? It seems unusual that you have three finite flows and you want to consume each of them completely from start to finish just to find out how they end up.

Comment: I am basically forced to use flows because of someone elses API and just want to check that the latest value from each flow is non-null

Comment: `lastOrNull()` doesn’t give you the latest value. If it’s a cold flow, it will start the flow from the beginning and suspend until the flow emits every value until it’s done, if it even has a finite end at all. If it’s a hot flow, it will suspend forever and never return.

Comment: If lastOrNull() doesn't give me the latest value - what does? Seems like the Flow API is not very "beginner-friendly"

Comment: It's not difficult to learn the basics as long as you read the documentation and understand the concept of a Flow being "cold" and what a "terminal operator" is. A cold Flow doesn't produce anything until you start iterating it with a terminal operator, so there is no concept of a latest value--there's no value at all until you iterate it. However, there is the **hot** Flow subtype SharedFlow. *If* you create a SharedFlow with a replay of **exactly** 1, you can get the latest value by using `first()`, but it's possible it has no values yet so it will suspend until it produces one.

Comment: There is a special subtype of SharedFlow called StateFlow that *always* has a value and so you can get its latest value immediately without suspending by simply using `stateFlow.value`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If I have a SharedFlow with a replay of exactly 1, why I cannot get the latest value with the `last()` but can get it with `first()`? If there is exactly single value, the first is the last as well.

Comment: `last()` can only return a value when the Flow completes. The name “last” is referring to the last value that will ever be emitted by the flow, not the most recent.